# Where to put filter, attribute and extension in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I just got done reading Rick Anderson's article on Securing your [ASP.NET MVC application](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/05/02/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-3-application.aspx). In the article he talked about creating new filter attributes.

```
public class LogonAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute 
{
     public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) 
     {
         if (!(filterContext.Controller is AccountController))
             base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
     }
}
```

and

```
using System;
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class AllowAnonymousAttribute : Attribute { }
```

My question is,  what is the best way to organize these filters and attributes?  Do I create a new class file for each? Do I create one class file for all filter and attribute?  Where is the best place to put it?  In the root folder?  in subfolder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have an MVCFilters directory and each attribute filter would get its own class.

And if we started to create a lot of custom filters we might break them up into sub directories like security and whatever else we had.

Comment: I downloaded the sample from the article and its doing something like you describe.  Thank you!

Comment: If I use the area, and create custom filters that be used in area, then MVCFilters direcory exist in root or in this area?

Comment: If its area specific it goes in the area.

Comment: Thank you @ShaneCourtrille So it goes in Areas/Admin/Model/MVCFilters or Areas/Admin/MVCFilters?

Comment: I would put it in Areas/Admin/MVCFilters as its not a model thing.